# Face areas in fipy

Tags: fipy

Is there a possibility to extract the area of a face between two cells in fipy?

I know that each mesh has got the property *cellVolume* and in the specific case I investigate, this allows me to deduce the relevant surface areas. Furthermore, I can obtain *faceCenters* and *faceNormals*. But wouldn't it be natural to include a property *faceArea* for a *faceVariable*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FiPy does have a face area property, but it's a member of the mesh class.

```
>>> import fipy
>>> fipy.Grid2D(nx=2, ny=2)._faceAreas
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

It's an underscore property which makes it hard to find.

Comment: To me, this is very surprising. In my case, it is a nice double check since I can also obtain the relevant face areas from cellVolumes. However, I can think of many cases where it would be useful to have easy access to faceAreas. I couldn't find any information on this underscore property on the fipy homepage...

Comment: Underscored names are, by Python convention, considered internal implementation details. We've been wrong before about what properties and methods users might need know about. Please [file an issue](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/new) if you'd like us to make this part of the public API.